# How to put more than one specicfication after the WHERE part when selecting data in php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am creating a website that takes data from the user and searches in some  database for a hall that meets all the users specifications so I search in the database using php pdo method by typing

`(SELECT * FROM thetablename WHERE place=$place,category=$category)`

But it doesn't work, I want the choose raw to have a hall name that I will get later and this hall contains all the specifications of the user together.

Comment: Please post your full code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM thetablename WHERE place=$place AND category=$category)
```

You need to use the `AND` keyword.

You could of answered this with some simple searching.

[SQL Where](http://sql%20where)